# Can I reach "/web" path from within a container in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I need to save a file in `/web/import` path and I am asking which is the best way to achieve this. I have a class defined in `/Service/SyncController.php` and it extends from `Controller`:

```
class SyncController extends Controller { ... }
```

That class is defined as a service also:

```
sync.service:
    class: PDI\PDOneBundle\Service\SyncController
    arguments: ["@service_container", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@request_stack", "%kernel.root_dir%"]
```

Do I need to pass the argument `"%kernel.root_dir%"` in order to access web path as `$this->webRoot = realpath($rootDir . '/../web')` or I can do it from `@service_container`? Which is the right way to get the path to `/web/import` in order to save files in there?

Comment: I think that `web` is not defined in Symfony so you may not be able to get its path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we use this configuration to do just this.

in parameters.yml

```
upload_path: "/images/uploads"
upload_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web%upload_path%"
```

we split path from dir just for simplicity of reading.

in the controller:

```
$work_dir = $this->container->getParameter('upload_dir');
```